# Use regex to find specific match between PHP anchors

Tags: regex

If I have the following code and want to return only the PHP block that contains "function xyz" using regex:

```
<?php
  function xyz(
    // Code goes here
  )
?>

<!-- HTML code here -->

<?php
  // Other code
  echo "Its done!";
?>
```

I tried to do the following regex: /(<\?php).*function xyz.*(\?>)/s to get the following result:

```
<?php
  function xyz(
    // Code goes here
  )
?>
```

But instead of getting the expected result, it ends up giving me everything between the first "<\?php" and the last "\?>".  Can anyone suggest the proper regex syntax to accomplish this?

Comment: Since PHP tags can lie inside of PHP tags, regexes aren't the right tool for the job. You'll have to write a lexer and parser. The bigger question, however, is why you are trying to lex and parse a PHP file in the first place.

Comment: The reason why I'm trying to do this is because my website got hacked and hundreds of my PHP files got malicious PHP blocks added to them. I was trying to write a php script to recursively go through all of my PHP files and remove the offending PHP blocks using a file_get_contents into a string, then use preg_replace to remove the offending PHP block, then file_put_contents to re-write the PHP file.

Comment: A useful [PHP tokenizer](http://php.net/token_get_all) exists. I made good use of it when analyzing a huge codebase for existence of deprecated/removed functionality prior to upgrading PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jack Maney made a good point, however, for your specific case you can simply use

```
/<\?php.*function xyz.*?\?>/s
```

You need to use the *ungreedy/lazy* operator which is a `?` that you insert imediately after a `+` or `*`. Those two quantifiers (* and +) are greedy operators, which means it'll grab the longest possible match instead of the shortest as you we're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following one:

```
/(<\?php).*function xyz.*?(\?>)/s
```

The only difference is that I changed `.*` by `.*?`. Read more about it [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) (under *Watch Out for The Greediness!*)